# How to cluster Hazelcast instances?

Tags: hazelcast

How to run two Hazelcast instances on two different machines within the same cluster?

[this is my configuration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVJTz.png)

I want to know how we can configure multicast and TCP in the *network* element for testing high-availability. I tried searching in many articles but could not find any relevant configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two machines, with static IPs, then the simplest way is to use the TCP/IP configuration.

Assuming the IP addresses or your machines are: `1.2.3.4` and `5.6.7.8` and you use the default Hazelcast port `5701`, you should have the following configuration:

```
<multicast enabled="false" />
<tcp-ip enabled="true">
    <member-list>
        <member>1.2.3.4</member>
        <member>5.6.7.8</member>
    </member-list>
</tcp-ip>
```

Comment: i am getting socket connection timeout when forming cluster. any suggestion on this?? please..

Comment: Socket Connection can be caused by many different reasons. First thing I'd check is if you have the port 5701 open on your machines.